# Laravel 5.6 Eloquent model can not use withTrash or onlyTrashed function

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5.6

I'm upgrade laravel from 5.4 to **5.6.23** 
and working with Eloquent Model like this

```
<?php namespace App\Model;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Category extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;
}
```

And I called Category with trashed function in controller

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers\Backend;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Model\Category;

class CategoryController extends Controller
{

    public function __construct() 
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');         
    }

    public function index(
        Request $request
    ) {  
        dd(Category::onlyTrashed());
    }
}
```

and it's show an error like this. Even normal get data will include all record with `softdelete` row

```
BadMethodCallException
Method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::onlyTrashed does not exist.
```

with 5.4 working fine but 5.6 not work for me
here is the result from `dd(class_uses_recursive(Category::class));`

```
array:8 [▼
  "Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Concerns\HasAttributes" => "Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Concerns\HasAttributes"
  "Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Concerns\HasEvents" => "Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Concerns\HasEvents"
  "Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Concerns\HasGlobalScopes" => "Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Concerns\HasGlobalScopes"
  "Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Concerns\HasRelationships" => "Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Concerns\HasRelationships"
  "Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Concerns\HasTimestamps" => "Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Concerns\HasTimestamps"
  "Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Concerns\HidesAttributes" => "Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Concerns\HidesAttributes"
  "Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Concerns\GuardsAttributes" => "Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Concerns\GuardsAttributes"
  "Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes" => "Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes"
]
```

Comment: Does `(new Category)->getDeletedAtColumn()` work?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir Not working

Comment: What's the result of `dd(class_uses_recursive(Category::class));`?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir update in question already

Comment: What error does `(new Category)->getDeletedAtColumn()` give you?

Comment: now it's return "deleted_at" with dd function

Comment: Did you change anything in meantime?

Comment: nothing change @JonasStaudenmeir

Comment: But `Category::onlyTrashed()` still doesn't work?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir yes this one not working, i was check on laracast 
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/withtrashed-isnt-working they have same issue too

Answer (score 0):

Ok i found solution. i try add boot function with parent

```
<?php namespace App\Model;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Category extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();
    }
}
```

then no error with `Category::withTrashed()` and `Category::all()` has filter softDelete out

Comment: In fact it shouldn't change anything. Can you include full `Category` model you use? Did you have custom `boot` method with your stuff?

Comment: im init new project with category model nothing fancy, no custom boot. but when im call `Category::withTrashed()` an error happen but if i put `parent::boot()` working fine.